# Incorrect code coverage percentage show up on the summary tab of the azure yaml build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On the summary tab, code coverage is shown as 57%. However, when I open the code coverage results file on the Code Coverage tab in Visual studio locally, it shows 84% code covered. What might be the reason behind it?

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Maybe coverage in last commit versus total coverage?

Comment: Please check whether my answer can help you. If not, you can edit your question and post the differences in your code coverage file between Azure DevOps and VS, so that people can investigate this question further.

Comment: Hello there, not get your latest news. Is there any updates for this question? Please feel free to comment~

Comment: Are you using Coverlet.msbuild to collect coverage data?

Answer (score 1):

> What might be the reason behind it?

**You can open the code coverage results file and compare it to the file in VS to see how they differ.**

One possible reason is that the code coverage in Azure DevOps includes additional .dlls.

You can open the code coverage results file to see whether it adds .dlls that you don't want.

If so, you can try the following solutions:

1. Use the run settings file to specify which .dlls to include. Note: Do not use exclude filters, but use include filters to cover what you want. You can click the document [Customize code coverage analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2019) for detailed information and steps.
2. Use [/ALLOBIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/allowbind-prevent-dll-binding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160) (C++) or [ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) (C#).
3. Delete all .pdb files and change your build process.

Comment: I have this same problem, and I'm using the ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute as well as the attribute in some csproj files